# How to retrieve information from an association table using Idiorm and Paris with only one query?

Tags: php, orm, idiorm

I am using [Paris](https://github.com/j4mie/paris) (which is built on top of [Idiorm](https://github.com/j4mie/idiorm)).

I have the following Model classes (example inspired from the [documentation on github](https://github.com/j4mie/paris#has-many)):

```
<?php
class Post extends Model {
    public function user() {
        return $this->belongs_to('User');
    }
}

class User extends Model {
    public function posts() {
        return $this->has_many('Post'); // Note we use the model name literally - not a pluralised version
    }
}
```

So now I can do the following (works well):

```
// Select a particular user from the database
$user = Model::factory('User')->find_one($user_id);
// Find the posts associated with the user
$posts = $user->posts()->find_many();

// Select a particular post from the database
$post = Model::factory('Post')->find_one($post_id);
// Find the user associated with the post
$user = $post->user()->find_one();
```

But I'd like to do the following aswell:

```
$posts = Model::factory('Post')->find_many();
foreach ($posts as $post) {
     echo($post->user()->find_one()->username); // generates a query each iteration
}
```

Unfortunately this creates a query for each iteration. Is there a way to tell Paris or Idiorm to take the associated information in the first find_many query ?

How are you supposed to retrieve information with Paris to minimize the numbers of query ? I'd like not to have to manually specify the join condition (this is the reason why I am using Paris and not Idiorm)

Answer (score 4):

I am the current maintainer of the Paris and Idiorm projects. Unfortunately what you describe here is a case for a custom query and not something that Paris was ever built to solve. The philosophy of Paris and Idiorm is to stick as close to the 80/20 principle as possible and your use case is in the 20.

It would be interesting to know how you ended up solving this problem.

Comment: So far, I only worked around the problem. On one project, I just switch to Rails. On the other project, I use a mixture of Idiorm and Paris, and all complex requests are done with joins in Idiorm. I really don't like mixing both Idiorm and paris, so I might come back and actually solve the problem. +1 for maintaining the project.

Answer (score 0):

I've had exactly the same problem, and ended up with this (a bit ugly) solution:

```
$posts = Model::factory('Post')...->limit($perpage)->find_many();
$user_ids = $user_lookup = array();

foreach($posts as $post) $user_ids[] = $post->user_id;

$users = Model::factory('User')->where_id_in($user_ids)->find_many();
foreach($users as $user) $user_lookup[$user->id] = $user;
```

Only 2 selects.  And later in template:

```
{% for post in posts %}
   <h2>{{ post.title }}</h2>
   by author: {{ user_lookup[post.user_id].username }}
{% endfor %}
```

But it only works if you don't have hundreds of posts showing on one page.